View Modifier prevents animation SwiftUI
The following view animates the content with a cube rotation effect when switching tabs. The animation works by clicking on the left or right side of the screen or swiping the tabs. When I add the .rect modifier, clicking from the 2nd -> 3rd tab does not animate. Anyone know why adding the modifier causes this bug?
import SwiftUI

struct cubeexample: View {
    @State var small: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var big: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var opacity = 1.0
    @State private var progress: CGFloat = .zero
    @State var selection = "Story 1"
    let data = ["Story 1", "Story 2", "Story 3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.opacity(opacity).ignoresSafeArea()
            TabView(selection: $selection){
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { story in
                    GeometryReader { g in
                        ZStack {
                            HStack(spacing: 0){
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.blue)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        if let index = data.firstIndex(where: { $0 == selection }), index > 0 {
                                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)){
                                                selection = data[index - 1]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.blue)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        if let index = data.firstIndex(where: { $0 == selection }), (index + 1) < data.count {
                                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)){
                                                selection = data[index + 1]
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                            Text(story)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        .frame(width: g.frame(in: .global).width, height: g.frame(in: .global).height)
                        .rect { tabProgress(tabID: story, rect: $0, size: g.size) }
                        .rotation3DEffect(
                            .init(degrees: getAngle(xOffset: g.frame(in: .global).minX)),
                            axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0),
                            anchor: g.frame(in: .global).minX > 0 ? .leading : .trailing,
                            perspective: 2.5
                        )
                    }.tag(story)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
    func getAngle(xOffset: CGFloat) -> Double {
        let tempAngle = xOffset / (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)
        let rotationDegree: CGFloat = 25
        return Double(tempAngle * rotationDegree)
    }
    func tabProgress(tabID: String, rect: CGRect, size: CGSize) {
        if let index = data.firstIndex(where: { $0 == tabID }), let last = data.last, tabID == selection && last == tabID {
            
            let offsetX = rect.minX - (size.width * CGFloat(index))
            progress = -offsetX / size.width
            var temp: CGFloat = progress - CGFloat(index)

            if (temp + 0.005) >= 0.0 {
                self.opacity = 1.0 - min(1.0, ((temp + 0.005) / 0.08))
            } else {
                self.opacity = 1.0
            }
            if temp >= 0.0 {
                self.big = temp
                if small > big {
                    //close view
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) {
                    self.small = temp
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RectKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGRect = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func rect(completion: @escaping (CGRect) -> ()) -> some View {
        self
            .overlay {
                GeometryReader {
                    let rect = $0.frame(in: .scrollView(axis: .horizontal))
                    
                    Color.clear
                        .preference(key: RectKey.self, value: rect)
                        .onPreferenceChange(RectKey.self, perform: completion)
                }
            }
    }
}

#Preview {
    cubeexample()
}


I fixed the bug by adding a variable named switchedToLast. If the tab is switched to either the first or last this var is set to true. If this var is true then the .rect handler function doesn't execute for .2 seconds which is the animation time of the tab change. I guess the state variables can't update during the transitions. The function tabProgress only runs for the last tab (didn't include logic for first tab) so preventing it from running for 0.2 seconds for the last tab change fixes it.
import SwiftUI

#Preview {
    cubeexample()
}

struct cubeexample: View {
    @State var switchedToStartLast = false
    @State var small: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var big: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var opacity = 1.0
    @State private var progress: CGFloat = .zero
    @State var selection = "Story 1"
    let data = ["Story 1", "Story 2", "Story 3", "Story 9", "Story 10"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color.black.opacity(opacity).ignoresSafeArea()
            TabView(selection: $selection){
                ForEach(data, id: \.self) { story in
                    GeometryReader { g in
                        ZStack {
                            HStack(spacing: 0){
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.blue)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        if let index = data.firstIndex(where: { $0 == selection }), index > 0 {
                                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)){
                                                selection = data[index - 1]
                                            }
                                            switchedToStartLast = index == 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.blue)
                                    .onTapGesture {
                                        if let index = data.firstIndex(where: { $0 == selection }), (index + 1) < data.count {
                                            withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)){
                                                selection = data[index + 1]
                                            }
                                            switchedToStartLast = (index + 2) == data.count
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                            Text(story)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                        .frame(width: g.frame(in: .global).width, height: g.frame(in: .global).height)
                        .rect { tabProgress(tabID: story, rect: $0, size: g.size) }
                        .rotation3DEffect(
                            .init(degrees: getAngle(xOffset: g.frame(in: .global).minX)),
                            axis: (x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0),
                            anchor: g.frame(in: .global).minX > 0 ? .leading : .trailing,
                            perspective: 2.5
                        )
                    }.tag(story)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            Text(selection)
                .font(.title)
                .offset(y: 30)
            Text(data.last ?? "NA")
                .font(.title)
                .offset(y: 60)
        }
    }
    func getAngle(xOffset: CGFloat) -> Double {
        let tempAngle = xOffset / (UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2)
        let rotationDegree: CGFloat = 25
        return Double(tempAngle * rotationDegree)
    }
    func tabProgress(tabID: String, rect: CGRect, size: CGSize) {
        if !switchedToStartLast {
            if let index = data.firstIndex(where: { $0 == tabID }), let last = data.last, tabID == selection && last == tabID {
                
                let offsetX = rect.minX - (size.width * CGFloat(index))
                progress = -offsetX / size.width
                let temp: CGFloat = progress - CGFloat(index)
                
                if (temp + 0.005) >= 0.0 {
                    self.opacity = 1.0 - min(1.0, ((temp + 0.005) / 0.08))
                } else {
                    self.opacity = 1.0
                }
                if temp >= 0.0 {
                    self.big = temp
                    if small > big {
                        //close view
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.05) {
                        self.small = temp
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                switchedToStartLast = false
            }
        }
    }
}

